# Why doesn't appcache's prefer-online work?

Tags: html, caching, html5-appcache

I am creating a simple admin application which have the following requirements:

- If user is online, fetch latest code
- Else, use cached code

Now, it appears that appcache always serves the assets from cache, regardless of online/offline connection. Why is that?

Here is my manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 102

CACHE:
/intake

SETTINGS:
prefer-online
```

And here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="intake.appcache">
<head>

</head>
<body>
  Something, Anything!
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get appcache to not cache the resources when an internet connection is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome ignores `prefer-online` or at least it used to. Firefox honors it, or at least it used to. So test it with Firefox.

Generally, do not rely on `prefer-online` as the user agent can choose to ignore it. Think of it more as advisory than compulsory.